# C# Random Floating Point Closed Interval

Tags: c#, random, floating-point, intervals

I'm surprised I couldn't find an answer to this anywhere, so perhaps I'm missing something.

The [`NextDouble`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of the [`System.Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) class returns doubles within the range of `[0.0,1.0)`. This is a half-open interval which returns `0.0 <= x < 1.0`.

I need a closed interval `[0.0,1.0]` such that `0.0 <= x <= 1.0`. In C++, I could use [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter), which returns me the smallest representable floating point that is greater than the passed parameter (e.g. `std::nextafter(1.0, 2.0)` would return `1.0000001192092895508`). I can't seem to find an equivalent in C#.

I'm working with tons of highly precise numbers (16bit), so although 1.0 may seldom appear, I still need it to have the ability to. And although the difference between `1.0` and `1.0000001192092895508` may seem negligible (and often is), the difference is one that will matter in this case.

After implementing a solution similar to [this](http://realtimemadness.blogspot.com/2012/06/nextafter-in-c-without-allocations-of.html) version of `NextAfter`, I sometimes get numbers larger than the maximum (e.g. `5.00000027008353` for `[0.0,5.0]`)

```
Random.NextDouble() * ((NextAfter(max, max + 1.0) - min) + min);
```

How can I generate random floating point numbers with a closed interval? I'm going to be executing this many times so preferably something that does not take too long to execute (like calling `Random` multiple times or using while loops and rejection sampling). Also, it's necessary to be unbiased, yielding uniform results (i.e. no number should be more likely to appear than any other number).

Comment: There is a couple of problems going on here, however let me try to understand this better, you want random floats (16bit) between (inclusive)  X and Y, as random as possible, i,e as little bias as possible

Comment: That is correct, although I could possibly downgrade to 8bit if necessary.

Comment: MSDN says: The actual upper bound of the random number returned by Random.NextDouble() method is 0.99999999999999978.

Comment: Right, which is why `Random.NextDouble()` is exclusive. I'm looking for an inclusive variant.

Comment: 1.0000001192092895508 is (approximately) the next 32-bit floating-point value after 1 (in the common IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point format). Did you mean the next 64-bit value, 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625?

Comment: You say you want something like `NextDouble` but are using 16-bit values. If you had closed-interval version of `NextDouble`, it would generate exactly 1 about one time in 2\*\*53, because of how finely spaced the double-precision numbers are. That is so infrequent that most applications will not be affected by any difference between a closed version and a half-open version. In fact, if you are converting the double returned by `NextDouble` to a 16-bit float, many of the returned values will round to 1, and adding one more out of 2**53 that results in 1 will not make any difference.

Comment: However, there is an issue that converting the result of a `NextDouble` that distributes its values uniformly to a narrower format may produce an uneven version. Around interior numbers like .125 or .5, there is an interval of some width *w* in which all the numbers round to the number. However, at 0 and 1, only numbers in an interval of width ½ *w* round to 0 or 1, so they will appear less frequently than other numbers. You probably ought to describe your problem more thoroughly and ask for a complete solution rather than just asking about closing the `NextDouble` interval.

Comment: Yeah this is my gut feeling, NextDouble will not be your friend here, i mean you have more than 1 problem for your bias, the converstion from 32 bit to 16 bit, and the fact of the uniform'ness between precision numbers in the float format. To get this as random as possible within your specs i think you are going to have to randomize this from a bit level, anyway that is what my spidey senses are telling me

Comment: I'm not truncating the doubles to 16-bits. I'm still using the entire 32-bits, but only care about the first 16-bits being precise. I'm using this for machine learning applications. Even if there is a 1/2**53 chance of landing exactly 1, which in most cases doesn't affect anything, I would still like the option to be able to produce that kind of result.

Comment: The core issue is that selecting from a space of 2<sup>N</sup> possible values can be done by generating N independent bits, so this is what the framework does.  You are trying to use a space of 2<sup>N</sup>+1 possible values, and that isn't so easy.  You could try factoring 2<sup>N</sup>+1 ...

Comment: Why don't you generate uniform integers in the range [0, 65536] and divide by 65536 (or any exponent between 16 and 30)?

Answer (score 2):

This seems straightforward:

- Decide how often you want 1.0 to appear on average. Say, one in every billion times.
- Generate a random integer between zero and two billion from the bell shaped distribution with mean of a billion of your choice. Call it n.
- Generate n random numbers on the open interval.
- Generate 1.0.
- Repeat.

Now you've got a sequence of random numbers on the closed interval where 1.0 appears the expected number of times on average. You get one expensive bell-shaped computation every billion or so, which amortizes out to basically zero cost.

Comment: I do not believe that this is one of the distributions that converges to a normal.

Comment: To get identically distributed independent appearances of the extra value, a geometric distribution would be needed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Answer (score 0):

Your bit representation of floats implies a limited number of distinct values. Determine the number of possible float values, get a random int in that range and map/convert this value to your float range.